# Android Shared Preferences

Tags: java, android

I have Activity 'A' and Activity 'B'.In the Activity 'A' , If i have 6 EditText and the user enter only in 3 then i exit my app on click the onBackPressed Button without submit the EditText data which is entering , and then whenever i restart my app i want to same activity 'A' on start up. But when i run and enter only 3 edit text and 3 remaining and i exit my app fro the first time and again i restart app the launcher activity 'A' is start but when i do the same at the second time it will Call second Activity 'B'.How can i do this.Can someone help me please. Thanks to appreciate.

Hare is my Activity code

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.registration_details);

        SharedPreferences prefs =  PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
        final SharedPreferences.Editor edit = prefs.edit();
        boolean alldataSaved=prefs.getBoolean("SecondRun",false);

        et_CompanyName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText_CompanyName);
        et_EmployeeName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText_EmployeeName);
        et_CompanyWebsite = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText_CompanyWebSite);
        et_ContactNumber = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText_ConatctNo);
        et_Email_Id = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText_EmailId);



        et_CompanyName.setOnFocusChangeListener(new OnFocusChangeListener() {          

            public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {
                if(!hasFocus)
                {
                    edit.putString("Company_Name"+appWidgetId,et_CompanyName.getText().toString());
                    edit.commit();
                    Log.e("Boolean Value" , " = " + appWidgetId);
                }
            }
        });


        et_EmployeeName.setOnFocusChangeListener(new OnFocusChangeListener() {          

            public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {
                if(!hasFocus)
                {
                    edit.putString("Employee_Name"+appWidgetId,et_EmployeeName.getText().toString());
                    edit.commit();
                    Log.e("Boolean Value" , " = " + appWidgetId);
                }
            }
        });



        et_CompanyWebsite.setOnFocusChangeListener(new OnFocusChangeListener() {          

            public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {
                if(!hasFocus)
                {
                    edit.putString("Company_Website"+appWidgetId,et_CompanyWebsite.getText().toString());
                    edit.commit();
                    Log.e("Boolean Value" , " = " + appWidgetId);
                }
            }
        });


        et_ContactNumber.setOnFocusChangeListener(new OnFocusChangeListener() {          

            public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {
                if(!hasFocus)
                {
                    edit.putString("Contact_Number"+appWidgetId,et_ContactNumber.getText().toString());
                    edit.commit();
                    Log.e("Boolean Value" , " = " + appWidgetId);
                }
            }
        });



        et_Email_Id.setOnFocusChangeListener(new OnFocusChangeListener() {          

            public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {
                if(!hasFocus)
                {
                    edit.putString("Email_Id"+appWidgetId,et_Email_Id.getText().toString());
                    edit.commit();
                    Log.e("Boolean Value" , " = " + appWidgetId);
                }
            }
        });






          SharedPreferences settings=getSharedPreferences("prefs",0); 
          boolean firstRun=settings.getBoolean("firstRun",false);

          if(firstRun==false)//if running for first time 

          {
              SharedPreferences.Editor editor=settings.edit();
              editor.putBoolean("firstRun",true); 
              editor.commit();
              //execute your code for first time
          } 

          else 
          { 
              if(alldataSaved == false)
              {
                  SharedPreferences.Editor editor=prefs.edit();
                  editor.putBoolean("SecondRun",true); 
                  editor.commit();
                  Log.e("Second"," Steps !!!!");
              }
              else
              {
                  Intent iSubmit = new Intent(A.this,B.class);
                  startActivity(iSubmit);
                  finish();
                  //Default Activity startActivity(a); 
              }

          }

        databaseHelper = new DatabaseHelper(this);
        databaseHelper.onOpen(db);


        radioGroup_FinancialYaer = (RadioGroup)findViewById(R.id.radioGroupFinanncialYear);


        btnSubmit = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonSubmit);
        btnSubmit.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                final String stringEmail_Id = et_Email_Id.getText().toString()
                        .trim();

                final String stringCompanyWebsite = et_CompanyWebsite.getText()
                        .toString().trim();

                if ((et_CompanyName.getText().toString().isEmpty()))
                {
                    et_CompanyName.setError("Field Can Not Be Empty !");
                }

                else if (!et_CompanyName.getText().toString().trim()
                        .matches("[a-zA-Z ]+"))
                {
                    et_CompanyName.setError("Accept Alphabets Only.");
                }

                else if ((et_EmployeeName.getText().toString().isEmpty()))
                {
                    et_EmployeeName.setError("Field Can Not Be Empty !");
                }

                else if (!et_EmployeeName.getText().toString().trim()
                        .matches("[a-zA-Z ]+"))
                {
                    et_EmployeeName.setError("Accept Alphabets Only.");
                }

                else if ((et_CompanyWebsite.getText().toString().isEmpty()))
                {
                    et_CompanyWebsite.setError("Field Can Not Be Empty !");
                }

                else if (!isValidUrl(stringCompanyWebsite))
                {
                    et_CompanyWebsite.setError("Invalid URL");
                }

                else if ((et_ContactNumber.getText().toString().isEmpty()))
                {
                    et_ContactNumber.setError("Field Can Not Be Empty !");
                }

                else if (!isValidEmail(stringEmail_Id))
                {
                    et_Email_Id.setError("Invalid Email");
                }

                else

                {
                    String stringCompanyName = et_CompanyName.getText()
                            .toString().trim();
                    String stringContactNumber = et_ContactNumber.getText()
                            .toString().trim();
                    String stringEmployeeName = et_EmployeeName.getText()
                            .toString().trim();


                    int selectedId = radioGroup_FinancialYaer.getCheckedRadioButtonId();
                    Log.e("selectedId "," = " + selectedId);
                    radioButton_FinancialYaer = (RadioButton) findViewById(selectedId);
                    strFinancialYear = radioButton_FinancialYaer.getText().toString().trim();
                    Log.e("strRadioButton "," = " + strFinancialYear);


                    databaseHelper.insertRegstrationDetails(stringCompanyName,
                            stringEmployeeName, stringCompanyWebsite,
                            stringContactNumber, stringEmail_Id, strFinancialYear);
                    System.out.println("Data Inserted Successfully !!! ");

                    Intent iSubmit = new Intent(A.this,B.class);
                    startActivity(iSubmit);
                    finish();
                }

            }
        });
    }

    // validating email id
    private boolean isValidEmail(String email) {

        String EMAIL_PATTERN = "[a-zA-Z0-9\\+\\.\\_\\%\\-\\+]{1,256}" + "\\@"
                + "[a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9\\-]{0,64}" + "(" + "\\."
                + "[a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9\\-]{0,25}" + ")+";

        Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(EMAIL_PATTERN);
        Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(email);
        return matcher.matches();
    }


    private boolean isValidUrl(String url) {
        Pattern p = Patterns.WEB_URL;
        Matcher m = p.matcher(url);
        if(m.matches())
            return true;
        else
        return false;
    }

    @Override
     public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
         if ((keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK)) {
             AlertDialog.Builder alertbox = new AlertDialog.Builder(Registration_Form.this);

             alertbox.setTitle("Do you wish to exit ?");
             alertbox.setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                 public void onClick(DialogInterface arg0, int arg1) { 
                    // finish used for destroyed activity
                     finish();
                 }
             });

             alertbox.setNegativeButton("No", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                 public void onClick(DialogInterface arg0, int arg1) {
                         // Nothing will be happened when clicked on no button 
                         // of Dialog     
               }
             });

             alertbox.show();
         }
         return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
     }

}
```

Comment: Your questions barely makes sense.

Comment: @ harvey_slash : Suppose i have enter only 3 edit text out of 6 and does not click on submit button and i have finish the Activity 'A'.And then again i restart my app then i want same Activity 'A' whenever i have not enter the 6 edit text and submit the value , does not call another Activity 'B'.

Comment: i think you should save a variable in shared preference and check this variable in each launch of the app if it fulfil your required condition then open activity B rather than activity A if i got your question you want to open activity B once user entered the value in editText field

Comment: @ Irshad Khan: I have save a variable in shared preference but how to check this variable in each launch of the app.

Comment: @Irshad Khan : Can you give me code.I have tried lot of but does not proper run.

Comment: @jvd what i understood is that your exact problem  if yes then i am  giving you the code for it???

Comment: @Irshad Khan : - My Exact problem is how to start my Launcher Activity 'A'whenever restart the app if I'm existing in between. And if I'm Entering the all edit text field and click submit. Then go to next Activity 'B'. Again I exit and restart then I have to launch my start Activity is Activity 'B' not launcher Activity 'A'.

Answer (score 0):

save a variable in shared preference like this i have did it before for login module if user is already logged in then my launcher activity will not be launch and

```
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = mPrefs.edit();
editor.putInt("login",201);
editor.commit();
```

you can check it in your launcher Activity like this

```
Intent intent;
if(checkFristLogin()){
          intent = new Intent(SplashActivity.this, MyNewMainActivity.class);
}else{
    intent = new Intent(SplashActivity.this,MainActivity.class);
     }
startActivity(intent);
```

**checkFirstLogin function is here**

```
SharedPreferences mPrefs;  // make this field  in your activity class
private boolean checkFristLogin() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
     if(mPrefs == null){
        mPrefs = this.getSharedPreferences("MyGamePreferences", android.content.Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    }
        if(mPrefs.getInt("login", -401)==201)return true;

        else return false;
}
```

Hope it will solved your issue

Comment: I don't understand this syntax = if(mPrefs.getInt("login", -401)==201)return true; How can i check all the edit texts in launcher Activity.

Comment: @jvd this code is checking that what is the value of "login" tag in the shared preference (-401) is default value and (201) is the value that you saved if login gets completed. if it is equals to (201) means user has completed his/her login before and will return true then accordingly startActivity(intent) will be called.

Comment: Means If i use =String strEmailId = et_Email_Id.getText().toString().trim();apedit.putString("EMAIL_ID", strEmailId);apedit.commit(); So i can try like this  if (prefs.getInt("EMAIL_ID", strEmailId) == strEmailId) {return true;}. But it shows error like = The method getFloat(String, float) in the type SharedPreferences is not applicable for the arguments (String, 
 String)

Comment: @jvd use (prefs.getString("EMAIL_ID", "demo@gmail.com").equals(strEmailId) )since you have stored it as string in shared preference

Comment: @jvd you can save all fields email-is, cmp-name etc. and make one string tag that will indicate that data has been submitted correctly and check it like i have given in my code.

Comment: @jvd Welcome upvote my answer if  it is useful for you.

Comment: But it get NullPointerException at this line =       if (prefs.getString("EMAIL_ID", copyEmail).equals(strEmailId))

Comment: Please Help me to sort out this problem .

Comment: it is going to a long chat between us and stackoverflow try to avoid this you can send your problem to my Email id and for time being check pref object whether it is properly initialized or not.

Comment: @ Irshad Khan : Sorry for late reply , my internet is not working properly .What is your Email Id .

Comment: @jvd khan.irshad49@gmail.com